# Alert user if input contains consecutive digits or characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following Javascript:

```
else if(serialNumber == (/([0-9a-zA-Z\_\\])\1{3,}/)){
            alert('Serial Number cannot have a single digit or character repeat more than 3 times consecutively.');
```

I ran the regular expression through http://regex101.com/r/dH3gQ0 and it is running like it should. I am not sure what I am missing in the code. What is happening is nothing. I put in a serial number with more than 3 consecutive numbers and the alert does not appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the `==` operator, this checks if `serialNumber` is the same object as the regex 
 `/([0-9a-zA-Z\_\\])\1{3,}/`, which is always `false`, what you instead should do is use   [`RegExp.prototype.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

```
else if ( /([0-9a-zA-Z\_\\])\1{3,}/.test(serialNumber) ) {
            alert('Serial Number cannot have a single digit or character repeat more than 3 times consecutively.');
```

Comment: Thanks. I used this along with a suggestion from above about lower case vs upper case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually test the expression to the string like so:

```
if(serialNumber.match(/([0-9a-zA-Z\_\\])\1{3,}/) !== null)
```

or more semantically correct:

```
if(/([0-9a-zA-Z\_\\])\1{3,}/.test(serialNumber))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should test it like:

```
var serialNumber ='TESTSERIAL9';
var reg= /([0-9a-zA-Z\_\\])\1{3,}/;
console.log(reg.test(serialNumber));
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example ...

If the allowed characters are `[A-Za-z0-9_]` then you can use `\w`

```
// true if 4 consecutive characters are entered    
if( /(\w)\1{3}/.test(serialNumber)){ 
  // your code/alert
}
```

If the allowed characters include additional backslash then

```
// true if 4 consecutive characters are entered    
if( /([\w\\])\1{3}/.test(serialNumber)){ 
  // your code/alert
}
```

Finally, above are case-sensitive so 'aaAAaa' would not result in an alert.
If you want a case-insensitive version then:

```
// true if 4 consecutive characters are entered    
if( /([\w\\])\1{3}/i.test(serialNumber)){ 
  // your code/alert
}
```

Good luck
:)